# Is there a boolean any-function in XPath 2.0?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Assume I have the following XML

```xml
<root>
  <a>
    <b>hi</b>
    <b>ho</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>foo</b>
    <b>barnacle</b>
    <b>baz</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>bye</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

I want to write an XPath 2.0 expression that matches an `a` element that has any `b` child which starts with the text `bar`, no matter which `b` child it is or how many `b` children it has.

I was thinking this would look something like

```
/root/a[starts-with(string(b), 'bar')]
```

but `starts-with` takes a string as input, not a sequence. So maybe something like

```xsl
/root/a[any(for $b in b return starts-with(string($b), 'bar'))]
```

but I can't find an `any` function in XPath 2.0. Had it existed, I would have expected it to take a sequence of booleans and returned `true` if any of the elements of the sequence were `true`.

I could emulate the `any` function "faking" boolean logic with integers like so

```xsl
/root/a[sum(for $b in b return if starts-with(string($b), 'bar') then 1 else 0) > 0]
```

but this is a hacky and difficult-to-read solution. I would prefer a better way.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, as I was writing this question, that the `any` function I sought exists, just under a different name: `some`. Technically, this is not a function, but it's own XPath expression with special syntax.

I should be able to write

```
/root/a[some $b in b satisfies starts-with(string($b), 'bar')]
```

to get the result that I want.

Comment: What's wrong with `/root/a[b[starts-with(., 'bar')]]`?

Comment: Unless multiple sequences and joins are involved, the expression `some $x in $y satisfies Z` can indeed be generally rewritten as `exists($y[z])`, where `z` is the same as `Z` but with references to `$x` replaced by references to the context item; or simply as `$y[z]` if we know (a) that $y is a sequence of nodes, and (b) that the expression is used in a boolean context.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I did not realize filter expressions `[…]` changed the context item, but that of course simplifies the required expression, and leaves out the need for the `some` expression.
Given, however, that the actual question I posed was whether there existed a function matching the `any`-function I sought, I will mark my answer as the accepted one, as it answers that specific question.